# lempel-ziv compression algorithm implemention

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x, compression

I wrote the following code for implementing lempel-ziv compression algorithm for the following sample string:

```
AAAABBCDEABCDABCAAABCDEEEEEECBBBBBBDDAAE
```

Code:

```
keys=[]
text = open('test').read() # contain of the string: AAAABBCDEABCDABCAAABCDEEEEEECBBBBBBDDAAE
index=0
t=time.time()

def sub_strin_check(text,index_num):
    n = 1
    while True:
        substring = text[index_num:index_num+n]
        if substring not in keys :
            print(substring)
            keys.append(substring)

            # print(keys[-1])
            return (index_num+n)
        else:
            n = n+1
            continue

while True:
    try:
        if text[index] not in keys:
            # print (index)
            keys.append(text[index])

            print(keys.append(text[index]),text[index])
    except:
        break
    else:
        try:
            index = sub_strin_check(text,index)
            print(index)

            print(index)
            index = index + 1
        except:
            break

res = str(keys)
print(res)

with open("result","w") as f:
        f.write(res)
```

but the result is:

```
['A', 'A', 'AA', 'AB', 'C', 'C', 'CD', 'ABC', 'ABCA', 'ABCD', 'E', 'E', 'EE', 'EEC', 'B', 'B', 'BB', 'BBD', 'AAE']
```

My idea is working with index number in string(text) and check if the substring that is sliced exit in keys dictionary or nut if it's not there add it. If it exists continue and check the substring by adding the next character.

Any help please to see where is my mistake?

PS: I know there are some lempel-ziv python code on internet, but I have to use this code.

PPS:
The lempel ziv algorithm works in this way. checks the first character in the given string if it not exit in the keys (dictionary) if it exits in the checks for the next character in the string and checks this new substring if it not exit adds substring and if exits in keys it add the next character and this process continue...for example for my string the output should be: `[A,AA,AB,B,C,D,ABC,AAA,BC,DE,E,EE,EEE,CB,BB,BBB,DD,AAE]`

Comment: What is your _expected_ output?

Comment: the lempel ziv algorithm works in this way. checks the first character in the given string if it not exit in the keys (dictionary) if it exits in the checks for the next character in the string and checks this new substring if it not exit adds substring and if exits in keys it add the next character and this process continue... for example for my string the output should be : A,AA,AB,B,C,D,ABC,AAA,BC,DE,E,EE,EEE,CB,BB,BBB,DD,AAE

Comment: Please specify more precisely the algorithm targeted: [LZ77 or LZ78](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78) or something else?

Comment: thank you for your answer. the lempel ziv algorithm works in this way. checks the first character in the given string if it not exit in the keys (dictionary) if it exits in the checks for the next character in the string and checks this new substring if it not exit adds substring and if exits in keys it add the next character and this process continue... for example for my string the output should be : A,AA,AB,B,C,D,ABC,AAA,BC,DE,E,EE,EEE,CB,BB,BBB,DD,AAE

Comment: (I don't see the improvement in reading that in three places rather than two. There is more than one "Lempel-Ziv compression algorithm" (use abbreviations sparingly), and there are several implementations and file formats.

Comment: (Tagging [tag:python], [tag:python-2.7] _and_ [tag:python-3.x] seems excessive - have a look at the tag descriptions.)

Comment: `where is my mistake` I think it is not documenting the return value of `sub_strin_check(text, index)`. (Do you want "the `else: sub_strin_check()`" to be part of "the `if text[index] not in keys:`-" or the first `try`-statement?)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the dictionary instead of a list for lookup. Then the conversion from dictionary to list is straight forward if required

```
input_str = 'AAAABBCDEABCDABCAAABCDEEEEEECBBBBBBDDAAE'

keys_dict = {}

ind = 0
inc = 1
while True:
    if not (len(input_str) >= ind+inc):
        break
    sub_str = input_str[ind:ind + inc]
    print sub_str,ind,inc
    if sub_str in keys_dict:
        inc += 1
    else:
        keys_dict[sub_str] = 0
        ind += inc
        inc = 1
        # print 'Adding %s' %sub_str

print list(keys_dict)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'AA', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'BB', 'BC', 'BCD', 'BBB', 'ABC', 'DA', 'EE', 'AB', 'EC', 'BD', 'EEE', 'AAA', 'DAA']
```

Reference for Algorithm:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgreLYa-81Y

Comment: `I would use the dictionary … for lookup` - why not a `set`?

Comment: `dictionary` has constant lookup time, while `list` is an array has O(n). `lists` are slow for lookup and Dictionary is made for this job.

Comment: `dictionary has [this], while list [has that]` - might explain why not to choose a `list`, but: why not a `set`? `Dictionary is made for this job` _which_ job? _element of_? Not really. Value for key? Sure.

Comment: Actually, I agree with you. **sets and dictionary** internally use hashing. Which means **constant lookup**. So either can be chosen. I was under the false impression that sets are immutable and would affect the performance. I stand wrong with sets anyway. However, you need to initialize set using `set()`. `[]` by default means list, `{}` means dict

Comment: Glad to be of help. If the code above does the job. Mark it as answered.

Comment: Basedon your referenced on YT, should not be the answer:

[A, AA, B, ...] and not [A, AA, C, ..] ?