# algorithm to reduce a string with repetitions of elements

Tags: python, string, reduction

I am interested to logic structure of a string that contains repetitions. I figured out a system I think it should work, but I not sure is the most efficient.

The idea is simple. The first element is taken: if the second one is a copy of the first one we got 1 repetition. I record this as one repetition and  then I take the first two elements and check if they are repeated in the third and the fourth element.

In this way I check if (from first element to half string size) there's a repetition of elements. The longest repetition is preferred.
This choice because this is a recursive process: I check inside the repetition if there are other repetition also there.

If no repetition are found, I crop first element and repeat the algorithm.

For instance: 
"ACRCRTCRCRTZZB"
became after the 1' run:
[{times:1, string:"ACRCRTCRCRTZZB"}]
after the 2' run: 
[{times:1, string:"A"}, {times:2, string:"CRCRT"}, {times:1, string:"ZZB"}]
after the 3' run: 
[{times:1, string:"A"}, {times:2, string:[ {times:2, string:"CR"}, {times:1, string:"T"}], {times:1, string:[ {times:2, string:"Z"}, {times:1, string:"B"}] }]

This notation can appear confuse, but can be view as: 
     A[2[2CR]T][2Z]B 
for "ACRCRTCRCRTZZB"

The problem is general problem, independent from the language. 
I wrote the initial code for this in python, thinking of its solution in the back end. 
Also a javascript solution (if it's solved in the frontend) will work for me.

the test

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest
from string_repetitions import StrPattern as sp

class TestStringRepetitions(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.str_ptrn = sp() 


    pass


    def test_fromStr2Tpl(self):
        str_ptrn = sp()


        a_li = []
        a_tpl = []
        b_li = [0, 1, 0, 1, ]
        b_tpl = [(0, 1), (0, 1), ]
        c_li = [0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3]
        c_tpl = [(0, 1), (3, 4), (4, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3)]
        d_li = [0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4]
        d_tpl = [(0, 1), (3, 4), (2, 1), (1, 4)]
        e_li = [0, 1, 3, ]
        e_tpl = None

        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.fromStr2Tpl(a_li), a_tpl)
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.fromStr2Tpl(b_li), b_tpl)
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.fromStr2Tpl(c_li), c_tpl)
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.fromStr2Tpl(d_li), d_tpl)
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.fromStr2Tpl(e_li), e_tpl)


    def test_logic(self):
        a1_li = [(0, 1)]  # only one row


        a1_lo = [{"times": 1, "rows": [(0, 1), ]}, ]
        b0_li = [(0, 1), (0, 1)]
        b0_lo = [{"times": 2, "rows": [(0, 1)]}]
        b1_li = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), ]
        b1_lo = [{"times": 5, "rows": [(0, 1)]}]
        b2_li = [(0, 1), (4, 3)]  # two row not repeated
        b2_lo = [{"times": 1, "rows": [(0, 1), (4, 3), ]}, ]
        c0_li = [(3, 4), (4, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3)]
        c0_lo = [{"times": 2, "rows": [(3, 4), (4, 3)]}]
        d0_li = [(0, 1), (3, 4), (2, 1), (1, 4)]
        d0_lo = [{"times": 1, "rows": [(0, 1), (3, 4), (2, 1), (1, 4), ]}, ]
        e0_li = [(0, 1), (3, 4), (4, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3)]
        e0_lo = [{"times": 1, "rows": [(0, 1)]}, {"times": 2, "rows": [(3, 4), (4, 3)]}]
        f0_li = [(0, 1), (3, 4), (2, 1), (1, 4)]
        f0_lo = [{"times": 1, "rows": [(0, 1), (3, 4), (2, 1), (1, 4)]}]

        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.logic([]), [])
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.logic(a1_li), a1_lo)
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.logic(b0_li), b0_lo)
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.logic(b1_li), b1_lo)
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.logic(b2_li), b2_lo)
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.logic(c0_li), c0_lo)
        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.logic(d0_li), d0_lo)
        # self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.logic(e0_li), e0_lo)

        '''
        def test_fromList2Logic(self):
        b1_li = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,]
        b1_lo = [{"times": 5, "rows": [(0, 1)]}]

        c0_li = [ 1, 0, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3]
        c0_lo = [{"times": 1, "rows": [(1, 0), ]}, {"times": 2, "rows": [(3, 4), (4, 3)]}]

        d0_li = [1, 0, 0, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3]
        d0_lo = [{"times": 1, "rows": [(1, 0), ]},
        {"times": 2, "rows": [(0, 2),
        {"times": 2, "rows": [(4, 3)]},], }
        ]

        self.assertEqual(self.str_ptrn.logic(b1_li), b1_lo)
        '''

if name == 'main':
    unittest.main()
```

the code I wrote is not finished: 
I wonder if I'm approaching the problem in the best way.

Comment: This looks a lot like the [lempel-ziv compression algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336798/lempel-ziv-compression-algorithm-implemention). See if the attached post helps

Comment: Thank you yatu for you suggestion.   My aim is a little bit different.   I'm looking for a transformation of 
'AAAABBCDEABCDABCAAABCDEEEEEECBBBBBBDDAAE'
 to '4A 2B CDE ABCD ABC 3A BCDE 5E C 6B 3D 2A E'